# Why service worker javascript appear instead of index.html

Tags: angular, service-worker

I have any angular application, I implement service worker, it caches index.html, css, js files.
But sometime, when application logout, and I tried to login again, it display the service worker js file, not the index.html file.
Do anyone know why it happen?

Comment: Could you please fill more detailed info for your project? Like how it sign in and sign out?

Comment: @Anduin, My application is inside another WAM server, so when go to application, it must be pass WAM, and WAM sever will do the authentication, after that they will forward to our application with token.